# Heroku Webhook Fails Sometimes

Tags: heroku, webhooks, dialogflow-es

I'm creating a chatbot with dialogflow and I have a webhook hosted on heroku (so that I can use python scripts). The webhook works fine most of the time. However when I haven't used it in a while it will always fail on the first use with a request timeout. Has anyone else come across this issue? Is there a way to wake up the webserver before running the script I have written?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heroku's free dynos will sleep after 30 minutes of inactivity.
Preventing them from sleeping is easy. You need to use any of their paid plans.

See https://www.heroku.com/pricing

Once you use a Hobby dyno, your app will never sleep anymore and you shouldn't be getting request timeouts.

Alternatively, you can also benchmark what's taking a long time to boot your app. With a faster boot time, the first request would be slow but wouldn't get a timeout.
Heroku times out requests after [30 seconds](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/error-codes#h12-request-timeout).

Comment: That's awesome, thanks for the answer. It's definitely from using the hobby dyno.